# SwiftUI - Button Action to Alert and take action

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to send alert based on a condition, but the Navigation link is executing regardless of the condition. I was hoping for an intercept.

Goal:

1. If condition is not me then do not launch new view
2. New View is launching and then alert.
3. I am sure my code is incorrect, but I am unsure how I should achieve this

Thanks in advance.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                //NavigationLink(destination: secondView()) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: checkState()) {
                        Text("Add to Cart")
                    }.padding()
                     .font(.system(size: 14))
                     .background(Color.red)
                     .foregroundColor(.white)
                     .cornerRadius(6)
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    } // End of the GetOrder Struct

    struct GetdOrderView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            GetdOrderView()
        }
    }
}

struct checkState: View {
    @ObservedObject var calcCheck = MealOrder()
    @State var showingAlert = false
    @State var myToggle =  false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    //Enter Action here
                    if self.myToggle == true {
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    } else {
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("This is a test")
                }.padding()
                 .font(.system(size: 14))
                 .background(Color.blue)
                 .foregroundColor(.white)
                 .cornerRadius(6)
                 //Insert Alerts
                 .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    if self.myToggle {
                        return Alert(title: Text("Showing Message"), message: Text("Cart is valid"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                    } else {
                        return Alert(title: Text("Showing Alert"), message: Text("Cart Empty"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Cancel")))
                    }
                 }                 
            }
        }
    }
}

struct secondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is the second test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small formatting fix

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
@State var activateLink = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: checkState(), isActive: $activateLink) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            Button(action: {
                if _YOUR_CONDITION_HERE_ {
                    self.activateLink = true
                }
            }) {
                Text("Add to Cart")
                    .padding()
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
            }
        }
        .onAppear { self.activateLink = false }
    }.padding()
}// End of the GetOrder Struct
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will implement tonight and let you know.